# Trying to get a data from sql database: what to enter into textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have text-box named `txtitemcode`,  when I type the item-code into text box I want to to display the corresponding data into grid-view or text boxes.

But it's not firing the code, I don't know where I am wrong, I search in the Google and keep change the codes , finally I got one still its not working.  I am pasting my code here..

```vb
Public Sub SelectItem(ByVal ItemCode As String)
        Try
            sql.OpenDbConnection()
            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ItemCode as 'Item Code',ItemName as 'Item Name' FROM tblItemMaster where ItemCode='ItemCode'"
            'SqlConn.Close()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, sql.SqlConn)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "tblItemMaster")
            dgvPurchaseOrder.DataSource = ds.Tables("tblItemMaster")
            sql.SqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I call this class from text lostfocus, click and some of doubted events, no luck ..

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?  Where is it "not working"?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It doesnt look like you are passing the parameter correctly

Comment: @njaeeb are you calling func like this `SelectItem(txtitemcode.text)` ?

Comment: Yes exactly.... I pass that function in textbox lost focus, is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the parameter correctly. Try this:

```vb
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ItemCode 'Item Code',ItemName 'Item Name' " & _
    " FROM tblItemMaster where ItemCode= @ItemCode"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sql.SqlConn)
Dim ds As New DataSet

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", ItemCode)

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(ds, "tblItemMaster")
```

Take a look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about it.

Comment: I call this function in txtitemcode text lost focus, after I type the itemcode and select the another text , that time its showing this error and no action happens.

Comment: oh my god its working, you are great... really thanks lot. Can you help me for this too I want to take data to text boxes instead of gridview.

Comment: Please create a new question for different problems and I will try to help. If this problem is solved consider [marking the answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208536) and upvoting it.

Comment: @NAJEEB be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer if it helps