# Display data from database to textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I trying to show the data from database to textbox , that what I write in textbox. 
this is my last code I got. here the data showing in to datagrid. instead of datagrid how to get the data to textboxes.

```
Public Sub SelectItem(ByVal ItemCode As String)
    Try
        sql.OpenDbConnection()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ItemCode 'Item Code',ItemName 'Item Name' " & _
  " FROM tblItemMaster where ItemCode= @ItemCode"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sql.SqlConn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", ItemCode)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "tblItemMaster")
        dgvPurchaseOrder.DataSource = ds.Tables("tblItemMaster")
        sql.SqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have no idea how to do that. please help me

Comment: please don't post same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213302/trying-to-get-a-data-from-sql-database-what-to-enter-into-textbox) again

Comment: i am sorry but its not same question that i ask last time. that time it was showing in datagrid ,this time i want to show the data to text boxes... please help me.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: or stuck in any error??

Comment: yea , but i am not sure is it correct way or , i try to create new sqldatareader , and run but no luck...Dim dr As SqlDataReader
dr = cm.ExecuteReader
 
If dr.HasRows Then
 
dr.Read()

txtItemName.text = dr.Item("ItemName")
 
dr.Close()
 
EndIf
like this, i am trying to get the codes that i can use. but really i am not sure about this.

Comment: i think you are trying to fill dgvPurchaseOrder with that dataset `ds`

Comment: yes... but how i can do that? can you give some idea please. using same dataset.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display a specific column data in the `TextBox`?

Comment: yes... instead of gridview. in above code i am using gridview.

Comment: Refer to each item in your table index inside the dataset for "tblItemMaster"... Like => `TextBox1.Text = ds.tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate textboxes try something like...

```
Public Sub SelectItem(ByVal ItemCode As String)
Try
    sql.OpenDbConnection()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ItemCode [Item Code],ItemName [Item Name] FROM tblItemMaster where ItemCode= @ItemCode"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sql.SqlConn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", ItemCode)
    Dim myReader As sqlDataReader 

    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If myReader.HasRows Then
        myReader.Read() 
        txtItemCode.Text = myReader.GetValue(0).ToString()
    txtItemName.Text = myReader.GetValue(1).ToString()

    Else
       MessageBox.Show("No data found", "No Data")
    End If
    myReader.Close()

    sql.SqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks... i guess we are almost there, this is my data types. itemname(nvarchar),qty(int),price(money). i tried your code  , its showing convertion type string "itemname" to int is not valid.

Comment: On which line? Not sure where that would be coming from!  What datatype is ItemCode?

Comment: nvarchar ,    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ItemCode", ItemCode)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                reader.Read()
                txtItemName.Text = reader.GetValue("ItemName")
                txtTotalQty.Text = reader.GetValue("TotalQty").ToString()
                txtPrice.Text = reader.GetValue("WholeSalePrice").ToString()
                reader.Close()
            End If
this is what i write now. can you check please.

Comment: If you use `GetValue` you do not pass the name of the column as you are `reader.GetValue("ItemName")` you need to pass the column ordinal (the column index), this is zero based. So if your select statement reads `SELECT ItemCode [Item Code],ItemName [Item Name] FROM tblItemMaster` ItemCode would be 0 and ItemName would be 1.  So change your code to read `reader.GetValue(0)` for ItemCode, `reader.GetValue(1)` for ItemName etc Add a .ToString() for any datatypes that are not nvarchar's

Comment: thanks a lot its working now. really i am lucky today, i learn lot from you people . thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should return the `ItenName`, `Qty` and `Price` into text boxes named `TxtName`, `txtQty` and `txtPrice`. You don't need a `DataSet` at all if you want to retrieve a single value.

```
Public Sub SelectItem(ByVal ItemCode As String)
        Try
            sql.OpenDbConnection()
            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ItemName, Qty, Price " & _
                                   "FROM tblItemMaster WHERE ItemCode = @ItemCode"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, sql.SqlConn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", ItemCode)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
               reader.Read() 
               txtItemName.Text = reader.GetValue(0)
               txtQty.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()
               txtPrice.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString()
               reader.Close()
            End If
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i have 4 textboxes(itemcode,itemname,qty,price).

Comment: but i am getting same error.  its showing convertion type string "itemname" to int is not valid